# check subtsring in excel column and return boolean result

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a excel file with 5 columns and last 'Skills Profile' contains data as " Skill1;#Skills2;#Skill3 ". Now I would like to modify excel and add a new column with each skill and it should contain a boolean value (True/False) in case that skill is present or not in the "Skills Profile Column". Below is the code I am trying but it's not working. Please suggest or correct this code. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col=0)
skills = dataframe['Skills Profile'].tolist()[0].split(';#')

for i, item in enumerate(skills):
  dataframe['item'] = dataframe['Skills Profile'].apply(lambda x: True if dataframe['Skills Profile'].str.find(item) else False)
```

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col=0)
skills = dataframe['Skills Profile'].tolist()[0].split(';#')

for skill in skills:
    dataframe[skill] = dataframe['Skills Profile'].apply(lambda x: skill in x)
```